# Insertar una fila con muchos campos en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Muy buenas noches comunidad

Quiero pedirles el favor para saber como insertar una fila que tiene muchos campos, en mi caso 23. Mi idea es no colocar uno por uno.  Muchas gracias y quedo muy atento

```
INSERT INTO producto (column_list)
VALUES ('20003', 'jabon', '25', '1', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3')
```

Un cordial saludo

Comment: Se hace asi.. salvo que saques los datos de otra tabla...

Comment: Reemplaza `column_list`por los nombres de cada una de las columnas